# Using Chaiscript without dynamically loaded libraries

Tags: c++, sgx, chaiscript

I'm working with Intel SGX and would like to use Chaiscript inside an enclave. SGX forbids the use of dynamically loaded libraries inside an enclave. Is there any way to use Chaiscript in such ways (I cannot compile using the "-ldl" parameter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ChaiScript 6.0 the standard library has been compiled into ChaiScript itself. So that aspect does not need `-ldl`.

What you are looking for is the `-DCHAISCRIPT_NO_DYNLOAD` option, which completely disables the ability to dynamically load libraries and does not require linking against the dynamic loader.

Answer (score 0):

See this comment from lefticus (Jason Turner) the author of Chaiscript:

> You should never try linking to the chaiscript stdlib, as the compiler
>   is warning you about. ChaiScript is fundamentally a header-only
>   toolkit. It also has the ability to use loadable modules, and it's
>   possible to compile the standard library as one of those loadable
>   modules.

Source is here: 
https://github.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript/issues/126